# Invariant description of fibre bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

The question:

What is the (or an) invariant definition of fibre bundle with fibre F and structure group G, without reference to a fixed cover of the base and transition functions for local trivializations?

The context:

In Steenrod's "Topology of fibre bundles", Part I, Section 2, he gives the definition of a fibre bundle with structure group G and coordinate system (local trivializations in which the transition functions live in some fixed subgroup G of homeomorphisms of the fibre). A fibre bundle is then an equivalence class of such (where you get to change local trivializations in a controlled way). This is all standard and written down in many other places, for example in Husmoller's book "Fibre bundles".

Then, at the end of Section 6, Steenrod says that Ehresmann (Sur la théorie des spaces fibrés) has a more invariant alternative definition of fibre bundle with structure group G, phrased in terms of an associated principle bundle. I wasn't able to get a hold of the reference, and the references of Ehresmann that I did find didn't seem any more invariant.

Comment: It should be possible to define a principal $G$-bundle as a map $Y \to X$ together with an action of $G$ on $Y$ whose quotient is $X$ and satisfying some other conditions I don't know off the top of my head. Then one can take associated bundles.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for principal $G$-bundles (I think the condition is just existence of a local trivialization), and yes you can take associated bundle. But then how do you go naturally go back, say without using a choice of local trivialization or base-point? Maybe you can't. Perhaps you just prove this construction is an equivalence of categories, and you have to make choices for the inverse equivalence. Any literature references on this point of view?